# How to edit text for a link that does not have an ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text of a link using javascript.  The problem is this particular link does not have an id.  I am unable to change the html, as this is a SharePoint page, and this particular link is created by a page layout, which I do not have access to.  Using IE Developer Tools, I see that the HTML surrounding the link is this:

```
<span id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">                   
<span>
    <a href="#ctl00_PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea_ctl00_SkipLink">
        <img width="0" height="0" style="border-width: 0px;" alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="" /></a>
    <span>
        <a title="State-Compliance" href="/sites/tax/Compliance/SitePages/State-Compliance.aspx">State-Compliance</a>
    </span>
    <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea_ctl00_SkipLink"></a>
</span>
```

The link I wish to change is the second one, the one with "State-Compliance" for the tooltip.
I looked at jQuery, and found I could use `$('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').find("a").text("Test");` to change the text, but it changes the text of all three links.  How can I change just the one?  Do I need to iterate through the three, or is there an easier way of getting the link I wish to change?
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm a c# developer, and this is my first experience using javascript.

Let me know if you need more information.

Warren

Comment: use foreach in jQuery, and look for a match on the title attribute, then set your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').find("a").eq(1).text("Test");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nxqAZ/1)**

Comment: Does `.eq()` use zero-based numbering? I think this would be better than Jason's answer in the long run, if I wish to change the Title on all pages than just the one I'm currently working on.

Comment: Yes, .eq() is zer0 based.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'll mark this as the answer instead then, since I'll be using this.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea a[title="State-Compliance"]')
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked perfectly, thank you.  It seems I cannot accept this as an answer for another 5 minutes, but I will as soon as I can.